# netscape.javascript.JSException: ReferenceError: Can't find variable : Test_Vote

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, javafx-8

I'm using JavaFx for loading htmp & javascript pages that uses jquery-1.9.1.min.js and pure_min.js.

Sometimes, when I launch application 
I encounter an exception like :

```
    netscape.javascript.JSException: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Test_Vote
    at com.sun.webkit.dom.JSObject.fwkMakeException(JSObject.java:128)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.twkExecuteScript(Native Method)
    at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.executeScript(WebPage.java:1427)
    at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.executeScript(WebEngine.java:948)
```

this error is randomly.

could you help me how to solve this issue, please ?

Environment used : Windows 7 64bit, JDK 1.8.0.51